# выполнение кода в docker заканчивается ошибкой ABNORMAL_EXIT

Tags: python, docker

Выполняю задание Яндекса, код обёртывается в докер и выполняется у них на сервере. При выполнении кода вышла такая ошибка:

> Completion status: ABNORMAL_EXIT
> Term sig: null
> Error code: 1

Вот код:

```
import json


trigger = {'price': [],
           'stock_count': [],
           'partner_content': []}
users = {}
products = {}


def json_replace(last: dict, simple: dict) -> dict:
    res = {}
    for key, item in simple.items():
        if key in last:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                res.update({key: json_replace(last[key], item)})
            elif last[key] != item:
                last[key] = item
        else:
            last[key] = item
            res.update({key: item})
    return res


def trace_out(trace_id, offer_id, differ: dict):
    my_users = set()
    for key in differ.keys():
        my_users.update(trigger[key])
        my_users = sorted(list(my_users))

    for user_id in my_users:
        resp = {'trace_id': trace_id, 'offer': {'id': offer_id}}
        data_user = users[user_id]
        offer = products[offer_id]
        for key in data_user[2:]:
            if key in offer.keys():
                resp['offer'][key] = offer[key]
        print(json.dumps(resp))


n, m = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(n):
    data = input().split()
    users[i] = data
    for j in data[2:2 + int(data[0])]:
        trigger[j].append(i)

for _ in range(m):
    data = json.loads(input())
    offer_id = data['offer']['id']
    try:
        if diff := json_replace(products[offer_id], data['offer']):
            trace_out(data['trace_id'], offer_id, diff)
    except KeyError:
        products[offer_id] = data['offer']
        diff = data['offer'].copy()
        del diff['id']
        trace_out(data['trace_id'], offer_id, diff)
```

Почему это произошло и как это исправить?
Помогите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!